# mysql select once (DISTINCT not working)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my sql table: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ff1c/3)

I trying get `id_user` once, but with two or more conditions in `WHERE` clause

If I use this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user FROM base_group_details WHERE id_category=3
```

I getting good result, but i wanted getting result with two or more parameters in WHERE, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user FROM base_group_details WHERE id_category=3 AND id_category=4
```

I should get 2 results, but it not working.

Comment: `id_category=3 or id_category=4 `

Comment: depending on your intentions, you should use either @IgnacioTellez's solution or Mureinik's solution.  Ignacio's will work if it's allowable for a value to exist with a category of 4, but not a category of 3, or vice versa.  Mureinik's will work if the only allowable values are ones that exist with both a category of 3 and 4.  Your intent isn't exactly clear, so it's difficult to know which of the two is actually correct for your specific use.

Comment: OR is bad for me, because i want narrow the search, no expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user 
FROM base_group_details 
WHERE id_category=3 and id_user IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT id_user 
    FROM base_group_details 
    WHERE id_category = 4 )
```

The Output is id_user 1 and 3

Answer (score 4):

No single row can have a category of both 3 and 4, so no rows are returned. One way to solve these types of questions is to group the result and count the number of relevant distinct categories each user has:

```
SELECT id_user
FROM   base_group_details
WHERE  id_category IN (3, 4)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_category) = 2
```

Comment: Might be worth noting, this will only pull back results for people that exist in both tables, but not for one specific table or the other.  This may or may not be what the OP was after.

Comment: It not working for me. For example: I want to find all id_user where id_category=3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

You can't have something like `id=3 AND id=4`, it can't be two exact values at the same time. Another approach you can use is using the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user FROM base_group_details WHERE id_categor IN (3,4)
```

You can then add even more values between the parenthesis.
I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT id_user, id_category FROM  base_group_details WHERE id_category IN ('3','4') GROUP BY id_user, id_category